# Select Max Row from Column

Tags: sql, subquery, db2-400

I have scan codes used in a table, but the table doesn't save just the newest scan codes. So I have order numbers with multiple items on those orders.

The issue is I need the last scan code on each item number for each order and not every time it has been scanned. Essentially I don't need to know that it has been scanned from prep to customization to shipping. I just need to know that it is in shipping. I get three results for one item number because it has been scanned three times.I don't need duplicate result from where it has been previously scanned.

The "S3DTNSEQ#" column is the number of times it has been scanned.I need to only keep the rows with the highest scan count. Anything lower than the highest scan count I need to get rid of. The 'Scan To' column is "S3DTSTO". So using the "S3DTNSEQ#" column to determine which row is kept is the idea.

```
SELECT 
    TMON as "order number",
    TMCPO# as "po#",
    TMRQD as "due date",
    S3ITNO as "item number",
    S3ORQT as "quantity",
    TMCUST as "cust#",
    TMNAME as, "cust name"
    S3DTSTO as "scanned to",
    TMSCHID as "sched id,
    MAX( S3DTNSEQ# ) AS "S3DTNSEQ#",
    S3DTADT as "maintained date" 
FROM 
    TSA400.NRPDTA.SOP114F1 SOP114F1,  
    TSA400.NRPDTA.SOA SOA,  
    TSA400.NRPDTA.S3O S3O,  
    TSA400.NRPDTA.S3DTU S3DTU 
WHERE SOP114F1.TMON = SOA.SOON
    AND SOP114F1.TMSHP# = SOA.SOSHPN
    AND SOP114F1.TMCUST = SOA.SOCUST
    AND SOA.SOON = S3O.S3ON
    AND SOP114F1.TMON = S3O.S3ON
    AND SOA.SOCUST = S3O.S3CUST
    AND SOP114F1.TMCUST = S3O.S3CUST
    AND SOA.SOSHPN = S3O.S3SHPN
    AND SOP114F1.TMON = S3DTU.S3DTON
    AND SOP114F1.TMSHP# = S3DTU.S3DTSHP# 
GROUP BY 
    TMON,
    TMCPO#,
    TMRQD,
    S3ITNO,
    S3ORQT,
    TMCUST,
    TMNAME,
    S3DTSTO,
    TMSCHID,
    S3DTADT
```

I imagine I need a subquery to do this, but i am completely lost, on how to do this. I apologize, the query was created in "Showcase" which uses where clauses extensively instead of joins.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu last sentence in original post, @ Ike, is the missing " on sched id causing a syntax error?

Comment: @xQbert I started formatting the query and then added the comment, didn't manage to go over the entire question. But I'll clean up the unnnecessary things

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu just a typo, sorry